# Error The element type "apex:selectList" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</apex:selectList>"

Tags: visualforce, selectlist

Below is my code 
VF PAGE

```
<apex:page controller="SurveyController" >
<apex:form >
    <apex:outputLabel ><b> Surveys: </b></apex:outputLabel>
    <apex:selectList value="{!surveyid}" size="1" multiselect="false">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!SelectedId}" />     
    </apex:selectList>
<p> 
    </p>                

<apex:outputPanel id="theForm">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:commandButton value="Display Survey" action="{!GetRecordPage}" reRender="theForm" id="bor"/>       
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!submit}" >
            <p>

                </p>
            <apex:repeat value="{!RecordFetching}" var="fetch">    
                <apex:outputField value="{!fetch.name}"/>
                <p>

                </p>

                <apex:inputField rendered="{! IF( fetch.Type__c == "Text"  , TRUE, FALSE) }" value="{!ResponseProperty.ResponseText__c}"  />

                <apex:selectList rendered="{! IF( fetch.Type__c == "Picklist"  , TRUE, FALSE) }" size="1" multiselect="false" value="{!selectedPicklist}">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!PicklistAns}"/>
                </apex:selectList>

                <p>

                </p>
            </apex:repeat>
            <apex:commandButton value="Submit Survey" action="{!SubmitSurvey}" reRender="theForm"/>
        </apex:outputPanel>

    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form>
```

CONTROLLER

```
public class SurveyController { 
    public string surveyid{get;set;} 
    public List<Survey__c> surv = new List<Survey__c>(); 
    public List<Question__c> Questions = new List<Question__c>();
    public List<Response__c> ResponsePage = new List<Response__c>();
    public List<Answer__c> AnswerPage = new List<Answer__c>();
    public List<Question__c> bdoc;
    public boolean submit {get;set;}
    public Answer__c AnswerProperty {get;set;}
    public Response__c ResponseProperty {get;set;}
    public string selectedPicklist{get;set;}

    public SurveyController() //Constructor
    {
        submit = false;
        ResponseProperty= new Response__c();
        AnswerProperty = new Answer__c();
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getSelectedId() 
    {            

        List<SelectOption> opt = new List<SelectOption>();           
        surv=[SELECT Id,Name from Survey__c];         

        for(Survey__c obj:surv)
        {
            opt.add(new SelectOption(obj.id,obj.Name));        
        } 
        return opt;
    }   

    Public PageReference GetRecordPage()
    {
        submit = true;  
        return null;   
    }

    Public List<Question__c> GetRecordFetching()
    {
       bdoc =  new List<Question__c>();   
       List<Question__c> Questions = [SELECT Name,Type__c from Question__c where Survey__c= :surveyid];
       //List<Answer__c> Answers = [SELECT Name from Question__c ];
       if(Questions.size() > 0)
       {
                bdoc.addall(Questions);        
       }    
       return bdoc;
    } 

    public List<SelectOption> getPicklistAns()
    {
        List<SelectOption> APicklist = new List<SelectOption>(); 
        AnswerPage= [Select Name from Answer__c];
        for(Answer__c obj:AnswerPage)
        {
            APicklist.add(new SelectOption(obj.id,obj.Name));
            System.debug(obj.Name);
        }
        return Apicklist;    
    }

    Public void SubmitSurvey()
    {
        if(ResponseProperty.ResponseText__c!=NULL){
            ResponseProperty.Survey__c=surveyid;
            insert ResponseProperty;
        }    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay the error is because you are quoting a value in double quotes within a double quote. The error is because of following lines.

```
<apex:inputField rendered="{! IF( fetch.Type__c == "Text"  , TRUE, FALSE) }" value="{!ResponseProperty.ResponseText__c}"  />
<apex:selectList rendered="{! IF( fetch.Type__c == "Picklist"  , TRUE, FALSE) }" size="1" multiselect="false" value="{!selectedPicklist}">
```

You can use single quote if within a double quoted string or vise-versa. Do the following this will fix your problem

```
<apex:inputField rendered="{! IF( fetch.Type__c == 'Text'  , TRUE, FALSE) }" value="{!ResponseProperty.ResponseText__c}"  />
<apex:selectList rendered="{! IF( fetch.Type__c == 'Picklist'  , TRUE, FALSE) }" size="1" multiselect="false" value="{!selectedPicklist}">
```